# Shift Values in column up or down for each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, shift

I have two data frame : one with the heating starting point and one with the heating ending point and that for each room.

Heating starting point

```
room_id
40   2021-11-23 04:12:00
40   2021-11-23 07:16:00
40   2021-11-23 21:47:00
40   2021-11-24 05:10:00
40   2021-11-24 08:08:00
             ...        
78   2022-02-11 04:17:00
78   2022-02-11 06:09:00
78   2022-02-11 18:59:00
78   2022-02-11 22:32:00
78   2022-02-12 00:20:00
```

Heating ending point

```
room_id
40   2021-11-23 03:21:00
40   2021-11-23 06:20:00
40   2021-11-23 07:32:00
40   2021-11-24 04:19:00
40   2021-11-24 07:08:00
             ...        
78   2022-02-11 02:51:00
78   2022-02-11 04:48:00
78   2022-02-11 06:41:00
78   2022-02-11 21:53:00
78   2022-02-11 23:35:00
```

I would like to shift the dataframe when heating starting point is higher then heating ending point and this for each room

What I am expecting :

```
room_id
40        NaN
40   2021-11-23 04:12:00
40   2021-11-23 07:16:00
40   2021-11-23 21:47:00
40   2021-11-24 05:10:00
40   2021-11-24 08:08:00
             ...   
78        NaN   
78   2022-02-11 04:17:00
78   2022-02-11 06:09:00
78   2022-02-11 18:59:00
78   2022-02-11 22:32:00
78   2022-02-12 00:20:00
```

I tried :

```
if [p_heat_start.groupby('room_id')['hour'].first()>p_heat_stop.groupby('room_id')['hour'].first()]==True:
    p_heat_start.groupby('room_id').shift(1)
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

If `df1` is your starting point dataframe and `df2` ending point you can try:

```py
# convert and sort dataframes (if necessary) 
df1["hour"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["hour"])
df2["hour"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["hour"])

df1 = df1.sort_values(by=["room_id", "hour"])
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=["room_id", "hour"])

ending_starting_points = df2.groupby("room_id")["hour"].first().to_dict()

df1 = df1.groupby("room_id", group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.assign(hour=x.hour.shift())
    if x["hour"].iat[0] > ending_starting_points[x["room_id"].iat[0]]
    else x
)

print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   room_id                hour
0       40                 NaT
1       40 2021-11-23 04:12:00
2       40 2021-11-23 07:16:00
3       40 2021-11-23 21:47:00
4       40 2021-11-24 05:10:00
5       78                 NaT
6       78 2022-02-11 04:17:00
7       78 2022-02-11 06:09:00
8       78 2022-02-11 18:59:00
9       78 2022-02-11 22:32:00
```

---

Dataframes used:

`df1`:

```
   room_id                 hour
0       40  2021-11-23 04:12:00
1       40  2021-11-23 07:16:00
2       40  2021-11-23 21:47:00
3       40  2021-11-24 05:10:00
4       40  2021-11-24 08:08:00
5       78  2022-02-11 04:17:00
6       78  2022-02-11 06:09:00
7       78  2022-02-11 18:59:00
8       78  2022-02-11 22:32:00
9       78  2022-02-12 00:20:00
```

`df2`:

```
   room_id                 hour
0       40  2021-11-23 03:21:00
1       40  2021-11-23 06:20:00
2       40  2021-11-23 07:32:00
3       40  2021-11-24 04:19:00
4       40  2021-11-24 07:08:00
5       78  2022-02-11 02:51:00
6       78  2022-02-11 04:48:00
7       78  2022-02-11 06:41:00
8       78  2022-02-11 21:53:00
9       78  2022-02-11 23:35:00
```